# Can my husband refuse sex, and what can I do about it?

Tags: nikah, sex

The past year and half, my husband only comes to me once in ten days to have sex with me once he comes (ejaculates) he promises me he'll come again as I want him physically near me, but he then will say he is tired, etc. This causes an argument and resentment towards him; it's okay for me to please him, but shouldn't it be equal--both of our enjoyment.  We have always had an active sex life; we both enjoy it and both love pleasing each other as it's important, but I am not happy with these selfish actions, so I feel resentment.

I want to know: Can my husband refuse sex, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I think he is allowed to refuse sex if he is mad at you. In case he is tired, did you ask for his fingers ? I saw on this site that the mouth is forbidden (do what you want about it). Or maybe with a better diet and sport it would be more frequent.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking whether Islam allow men to have pleasure while not respecting women right to the pleasure then of course not. It is actually advised in literature, for man to delay the orgasm until his wife's.

It is not wise to advice you and this is not a forum for advising people on their personal lives. Please seek advice from your elders.

Comment: -1 "seek advice from elders" not every old person is knowledgable in religious matters